# Graph Serialization (Blank Node labels)

Tags: jena

I'm attempting to do some graph normalization following the [URDNA2015 algorithm](https://json-ld.github.io/normalization/spec/#normalization-state).

If I'm understanding the spec, blank nodes should have labels like _:c14nX where X is an incrementing counter.

I can produce a graph that has blank nodes with these labels, but when serializing the graph to NTRIPLES these run through NodeFmtLib#encodeBNodeLabel which performs some encoding -- at the very least always prefixes the resulting node with 'B'.  For example c14n92 -> Bc14n92 or _:c14n92 -> BX5FX3Ac14n92 due to hex encoding.

My serialization code is very basic currently:

```
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        RDFDataMgr.write(sw, normalizedGraph, Lang.NTRIPLES);
```

What is the suggested way of having finer control over this serialization?

EDIT:
One approach I found that works, but I'm not sure if it is the recommended way:

```
RDFWriterRegistry.register(RDFFormat.NTRIPLES_UTF8, new CustomWriterGraphRIOTFactory());
```

Then implement a chain of classes that override:

- WriterGraphRIOTFactory
- NTriplesWriter
- StreamRDFLib
- WriterStreamRDFPlain
- NodeFormatter

to ultimately get to a place of overriding formatBNode:

```
public class CustomNodeFormatter extends NodeFormatterNT {
    public CustomNodeFormatter(CharSpace charSpace) {
        super(charSpace);
    }

    @Override
    public void formatBNode(AWriter w, String label) {
        w.print(label);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Jena writers work on graphs and a graph is a set of triple - unordered. As triples can be deleted and re-added, order isn't so easy even in a single threaded program because changes to the graph may reorder hash tables.

If you are doing this from JSON-LD - Jena currently uses jsonld-java - check whether the JSON-LD parsing is in a consistent order and labelling.

If you want to respect the order in syntax in other formats, look at parsing files to a `StreamRDF` object (- the parser output stream,  - as well as having a custom FactoryRDF (which controls the label used for the blank node - you could for example make them 1,2,3 at this point).

RDFParser.create().source(...).factory(FactoryRDF).parse(StreamRDF);

Note when doing it via output without control of the input the order of output may change from run to run as blank nodes get different ids each parser run.